# Transforming data to normal distribution in R

Tags: r, linear-model

I've imported some data from Excel, and I'd like to use the `lm` function to create a linear regression model of the data. 
To check if the data is normally distributed I've used `qqplot` and `qqline`.
[image: QQplot]

I'd like to see if it would help if I log transformed Y, but R tells me that log isn't meaningful for factors, but I don't see why R tells me that what I am trying to transform is a factor, since it isn't an integer.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how BK$Aktiekurs looks like and tell us what data type is it?

Comment: 1. There's no assumption in regression that the response variable (nor any of the other variables) has a normal distribution. 2. Why do you have the 'categorical data' tag? there's no suggestion that the variable you're looking at there is categorical. Can you say more about what these numbers are?

Comment: Hey, sorry about the wrong tag.
Here is how the data looks:
https://imgur.com/a/qlS7pJQ

Comment: Please add the result of `str(BK)` to your question, also `summary(BK$Aktiekurs)`. Chances are, you made a mistake when importing data from Excel. `Aktiekurs` hints to German as your language, yet the values have decimal points as in `41.03`. If there is one single line with a comma as in `41,03` R will read the whole column as factor, not as numeric. Finally never state " R tells me that" but always include the complete error message.

Comment: I turned my above comment into an answer.

Comment: I've voted to re-open. The excellent answer of @Bernhard makes it highly plausible that the problem reported is a side-effect of incorrect import into R. The answer requires statistical understanding, and is not about something totally R-specific like the syntax to use, so I think this is on-topic.

Comment: I've voted to reopen as the side aspect of what should be normally distributed in linear regression is a statistical topic and has seen only very little attention so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading data into R is often more difficult then expected and beginners tend to read in numeric data as factors. It is therefore always advisable to check the structure of your data with the `str` command after reading in data.

Take the following code as an example

```
test <- read.table(text="41.2 15
                         42.3 16
                         43.4 17
                         44,5 18")
```

At first glance, that looks ok and R throws neither an error nor a warning. `str`, however, reveals that the first column was read as a factor:

```
> str(test)
 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 4 levels "41.2","42.3",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ V2: int  15 16 17 18
```

And it takes a closer look at the code to find the reason.

Unfortunately, if you've read your data as factor, R will consider the levels of the factor as integers and therefore not throw an error when plotting the data. Let's plot the `qqnorm` of the integers from 1 to 100:

```
qqnorm(1:100)
```

[image]

That looks a lot like the plot in the question (the plot in the question is not as smooth and I assume there are ties in the data, so there are factor levels that are used more then once in the original data).

So the reason for the error in R is probably a problem in reading the data, because not every cell in that column looks like a numeric to R.

**However** as – Glen_b -Reinstate Monica stated: Normal distribution of your values does not matter for linear regression. A normal distribution of the residuals is preferable.

Comment: (+1) Very nice analysis. A quantile normal plot of a uniform looks like ... a quantile plot of a normal.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for editing!